# What is the fastest I/O strategy or method for sockets programming in C for FreeBSD or NetBSD?

Tags: c, http, sockets, networking, freebsd

I am researching network sockets programming in C. What is the fastest (highest performance) I/O strategy to implement for FreeBSD and/or NetBSD? Specifically, if I were to implement an HTTP/HTTPS webserver in C for FreeBSD/NetBSD, what is the most efficient method to receive the data?

I've read these resources, but seems that I could not find the answer:
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/index.html
http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Comment: c10k should have answered your questions. BTW, low latency and high throughput sometimes are opposing objectives. Hence you need to define "fastest".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beej's guide to network programming is an atrocity that has become the core of far too many people's understanding of sockets programming. That said, what you're really asking for is a high-speed way of handling *file descriptors*, and on the BSDs, that's the kqueue framework[1].

nginx/lighttpd/thttpd(i think) all have kqueue code you can learn from.

[1] http://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf

Comment: Why do you say Beej's guide is an atrocity?